# Skybox not rendering correctly when I switched platform to android on unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a skybox in my 2d game but its not rendering correctly and is showing these random rainbow colors and low quality.
It was working fine when the platform was windows but quality changed when I switched it to android.

[image: Image atached]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the unity shader that is used for **HDRI** skyboxes uses *half* values in the shader code.

Half on windows is treated as a 32-bit floating point number (float), but on android it is half precision, which makes your background banded.

You can either create your own background shader for this, or you can try changing the background image to **LDR** instead, which would fix the problem too.

Comment: Do u have any recommended tutorial for that?